# Azure ACS alternative for ADFS mobile authentication

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, jwt, adfs2.0

I've been using azure ACS to authenticate my mobile clients with corporate ADFS to my asp.net server app. I managed not only to have it working nicely in the web browser but also on mobile apps (with webview to get a jwt token that would then be sent to the server to be validated and generate the app auth token).

But unfortunately [Azure ACS is being discontinued](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/acs-access-control-service-namespace-creation-restriction/) so I have to look for an alternative.

Using [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-lob-application-adfs) I managed to have ADFS auth directly without any external service and that is a HUGE plus for me since some customers might have internet restrictions on their intranet.

The problem begins when trying to also implement this for the native clients (Windows WPF, Android and iOS) since I can't find a solution for these cases.

ADAL for Android and iOS [seems to require Windows Server 2012 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn633593.aspx). This restriction is a big no no.

I found a 3rd party auth provider [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) but I really want to avoid external services.

There's also Azure B2C Authentication but it has the same issue of external services.

Is there a way to implement what I had with Azure ACS directly on ADFS? What I need is a way to get a jwt token (or even SAML2 token) directly from ADFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom solution for my needs. Basically I implemented a solution akin to ACS flow.

The apps load a special login page on a webview that redirects the browser to the ADFS challenge page with a final callback to my webapp. There I notify the app with the token by the usage of notification javascript call like ACS does:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Loading...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try{
            window.external.notify('@ViewBag.Result');
        }
        catch(err){
            alert("Error ACS50021: window.external.notify is not registered.");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This way my app will not handle the user credentials directly and I no longer need external services :)

And unlike ACS I have direct control on the last step and I can export the token via a redirect to a custom protocol that helps the implementation on iOS (on ACS we had to inject javascript to the page in the webview to achieve this).

Answer (score 0):

ACS uses WS-Fed which is what that sample uses as the protocol.

Mobile devices use OAuth which is why you need ADFS 3.0 (limited support) or ADFS 4.0 (full support plus OpenID Connect).

If you just want ADFS to return a JWT token instead of a SAML one, refer to this [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/maheshu/2015/05/26/json-web-token-jwt-support-in-adfs/).

> Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust –TargetIdentifier ‘urn:MyWebApp’ –EnableJWT
>   $true

However, that requires ADFS 3.0.

The other way is to use WCF. This invokes the WS-Fed active profile which returns a SAML token as a web service as per this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2011/08/17/federated-security-how-to-setup-and-call-a-wcf-service-secured-by-adfs-2-0/).

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately none of those alternatives really work for me. I'm limited to ADFS 2.0 at best and the WCF alternative would require my apps to be aware of the user credentials on the AD and that is a real issue with some customers.

Comment: Yeah - although there are WCF flows that use certificates.